# When i create ul tags with javascript css does not work

Tags: javascript, css

where is the code :
[TestArea](http://jsfiddle.net/tjuu79mu/)

when i create the ul elements the css set for them is not working...
is there another way to set css ?

this is the css that is not working when the elements are created:

```
ul li{
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
    width: 13%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 7px;
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
}
```

it seems that it works with other tags, the problem is only with ul.....

Comment: Can you send your JS code please?

Comment: See your markup and you will get it why it isn't working

Comment: When will people learn that only posting code elsewhere always results in downvotes and an early closure?

Comment: @HoboSapiens We encourage them to learn themselves first

Comment: Anyways a hint, your `asdf` in the `div` is spoiling your markup

Answer (score 3):

Your `li` tags simply aren't inside your `ul`, so your selector doesn't match.
I updated your fiddle with a possible solution: http://jsfiddle.net/tjuu79mu/1/

```
function drawDays() {
    var x = document.getElementById("innerElement");
    var html = "";
    html += "<ul>"
    for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
       html += "<li>" + "nonononono" + "</li>";
    }
    html += "</ul>";
    x.innerHTML = html;
}

drawDays();
```

Answer (score 2):

**Problem:**

When you add `<ul>` to the innerHMTL, the browser makes this into a complete element. So that means that all the `li` elements will not be added inside but after the `ul`. That's why the CSS selector doesn't match. You can see this when you right-click one of the elements and select 'inspect element'. You will see the html of the `li` element and its siblings, preceeded by an empty `<ul</ul>`.

[image]

**Solution:**

A simple fix that still uses innerHTML, is to generate all the html in a string and insert it at once. This is probably more efficient too, since it triggers only one change to the DOM.

```
function drawDays() {
    var x = document.getElementById("innerElement");
    var items = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        items += "<li>" + "nonononono" + "</li>";
    }
    x.innerHTML = "<ul>" + items + "</ul>";
}

drawDays();
```

Alternatively, you can use `document.createElement()` or even a library like jQuery to help you insert the HTML, but for a simple task like this, innerHTML will do the trick just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `document.createElement()` to create HTML elements. Your code doesn't effectively append the proper elements within the proper parent, and the way you're creating the HTML makes it a little harder to debug. Here is an updated JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tjuu79mu/2/

```
function drawDays() {
    //get the containing element
    var x = document.getElementById("innerElement");
    //create and append the list element to the container
    var ul = document.createElement('ul');
    x.appendChild(ul);

    for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        // create an element, add some text content to it, then append it to the list element
        var li = document.createElement('li');
        li.innerText = 'testing testing';
        ul.appendChild(li);
    }
}

drawDays();
```

Comment: Yes, you should, that is a mistake. Fixed.